# AWS load balancer 504 Gateway Timeout for only one endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-api-gateway

I am getting 504 for only one endpoint in my service. All other endpoints are working without any issue.
My rules are as follows:

```
IF                                        THEN
Host is example.com                       Forward to:
Path is /abc?/*                           <load balancer URL1>

IF                                        THEN
Host is example.com                       Forward to:
Path is /*                                <load balancer URL1>
```

The endpoint works locally so there is no issue with the code.

1. The target groups are healthy.
2. I also changed the timeout to 120s but it still returns 504. Someone asked me to hit `<alb-dns>/endpoint` but then I found out that the rules are specifically for `example.com` and hence I was getting 404 which apparently is not an issue.

Can someone help!

Answer (score -1):

looking at your issue timed out,it might be possible there is some issue with your sg or tg,i cant exactly say what it is as you have not mentioned which load balancer you are using and the configs

Comment: SG or TG? Are you talking about the security groups. I am using an application load balancer. What configs are you looking for?

Comment: When I was hitting the endpoints, I found that the requests are going to second target group which is for frontend. It might be because the frontend and backend share the same space and load balancer is sending the requests to the pods.